# In couchdb How to get sorting on value with reduce _count

Tags: couchdb

```
"myview": {
       "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.type == 'user')  emit(doc.city,null)}",
       "reduce": "_count"
   },
```

It return city with count in value. Using group=true

How to sort this data base on highest value? Want to get most popular city first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list to sort your resultset. Following function can sort anytype of a resultset on value.

```
"sort": "function() {
        var row;  
        var rows=[]; 
        while(row = getRow()) 
        {  
            rows.push(row) 
        } 

        rows.sort(function(a, b) 
        { 
             return a.value - b.value;
        }); 
        rows.reverse();
        send(JSON.stringify({\"rows\" : rows})) 
    }"
```